# Anypoint Studio: Test While Running Separate Application

Tags: unit-testing, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, munit

I have two applications in Anypoint Studio, Foo and Bar. The bar stands alone, but Foo has a dependency on Bar (through an HTTP Request). I have already tested Foo as a standalone application using mocks for the calls to Bar. However, I would like to write an MUnit test which will test the full interaction (i.e. no mocking). I thought that running Bar, then running the Foo test would work, but this returns a 500 error every time.

Is it possible to perform a test like this in Anypoint Studio?

---

**UPDATE:**

It appears this was a proxy issue. Problem is now resolved.

Comment: As I understand you tried to launch the Bar app before running Foo tests. This seems the right approach for proper integration testing. How did you configure Foo to interact with Bar? Can you describe your 500 error in details? Logs and flow snippets might help. 
Maybe you deployed your apps properly and this 500 error means that Foo or Bar has a bug somewhere ;)

Comment: @PierreB Will update with logs, one moment! When I run Bar and Foo together (not in test mode), I'm able to get good results. However, these are manual tests, and therefore don't have any guarantees (e.g. assert statements).

Comment: Huh, I reran the application to get the logs, and suddenly things are working. I think there may have been a proxy issue at play. I'll close out this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're facing a similar issue, check your proxy settings. I found that I had started Bar, after which my proxy changed, and then I started Bar. As such, they were unable to communicate.